# Converting Data Types in Multiple Columns to Date

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm new to Python3 and I've been searching for a way to convert multiple string columns to dates using the to_datetime function but haven't had any luck. Currently, I have 4 columns that need to be converted from their originating data type to a date ("yyyy-mm-dd"). Below is a sample of the code I've written, while it works fine, I'd like to condense the total number of lines written to accomplish this.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/Desktop/test_data.csv")
print(df.dtypes)
df['Dob'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Dob'], format='%Y%m%d', errors='coerce')
df['Appt_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Appt_Date'], format='%Y%m%d', errors='coerce')
df['Payment_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Payment_Date'], format='%Y%m%d', errors='coerce')
df['Collection_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Collection_Date'], format='%Y%m%d', errors='coerce')

print(df)
```

I would use astype if it wasn't critical that these dates must be in "yyyy-mm-dd" format (unless there is a way to do it with astype that I'm unaware of). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe use loop?

```
date_cols = ['Dob','Appt_Date','Payment_Date','Collection_Date']

for col_name in date_cols:
    df[col_name] = pd.to_datetime(df[col_name], format='%Y%m%d', errors='coerce')
```

Comment: That worked perfectly! Being new to Python, I didn't even think to use a loop for that. Thank you for the help!